# Change Thumbnail View to special fields

Tags: 2013, list, picture-library, image, thumbnail

I am trying to setup a Picture Library in Sharepoint 2013.

When I hover above the graphic pic, it will show up with the name in the first line and the file type in the second row.

I would like to instead of file type show the description of the file.

[image]

How can this be done?